# Unable to resolve the OpenID Configuration with the provided Issuer (JHipster with KeyCloak)

Tags: spring-security, jhipster, keycloak

I started keycloak by docker-compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up -d
and then gradlew
in my project exception occurred as

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration' defined in file [G:\mymobile\app\build\classes\java\main\com\mycompany\myapp\config\SecurityConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: 
Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; 

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Unable to resolve the OpenID Configuration with the provided Issuer
of "http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster
```

SecurityConfiguration.java:

```java
package com.mycompany.myapp.config;

import com.mycompany.myapp.security.*;

import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import  org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import com.mycompany.myapp.security.oauth2.AudienceValidator;
import com.mycompany.myapp.security.SecurityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUserAuthority;
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import com.mycompany.myapp.security.oauth2.JwtAuthorityExtractor;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.myapp.config.*"})
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.oidc.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuerUri;

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;
    private final JwtAuthorityExtractor jwtAuthorityExtractor;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(CorsFilter corsFilter, JwtAuthorityExtractor  jwtAuthorityExtractor, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
        this.jwtAuthorityExtractor = jwtAuthorityExtractor;
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
                .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
                .antMatchers("/content/**")
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
                .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
                .and()
                .headers()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self'            'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
                .and()
                .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
                .and()
                .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
                .and()
                .frameOptions()
                .deny()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthorityExtractor)
                .and()
                .and()
                .oauth2Client();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    /**
     * Map authorities from "groups" or "roles" claim in ID Token.
     *
     * @return a {@link GrantedAuthoritiesMapper} that maps groups from
     * the IdP to Spring Security Authorities.
     */
    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                mappedAuthorities.addAll(SecurityUtils.extractAuthorityFromClaims(oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo().getClaims()));
            });
            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusJwtDecoderJwkSupport jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoderJwkSupport)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuerUri);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new    AudienceValidator(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getOauth2().getAudience());
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuerUri);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

Comment: I formatted your question because it was unreadable, please look at what I have done to learn how to do it.I have also fixed the tags and set a more descriptive title. Hope you'll get more help with this.

Comment: What happens if you try to access http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/jhipster/.well-known/openid-configuration?

Comment: thank you so much for formatting.it does not show server is running at 8080.application is build successful throwing above exception.

Comment: Sorry, the url should be on port 9080, like: http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/.well-known/openid-configuration. If this endpoint is not returning a json, your problem is on keycloak server rather than your app.

Answer (score 3):

From your exception message I assume you have configured in *application.properties*

> spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:9080/**auth**/realms/jhipster

The error occurs - as in the comments stated - when the openid-configuration can not be loaded by calling *[issuer-uri]/.well-known/openid-configuration*.

When you call *http://localhost:9080/realms/jhipster/.well-known/openid-configuration* (without */auth/*) you should receive the json and therefor the application should run when you adjust the *issuer-uri* accordingly:

> spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:9080/realms/jhipster

(without */auth/*)

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer might help someone else.

In my case, the config was not created properly and the issue was with `keycloak`

[image]
after fixing the config file the service works properly.

So make sure the keycloak return the proper JSON, in my case it was null

http://localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster

[image]